# LINQ/DataTable query for repeats

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datatable, group-by

I am trying to convert a SQL statement into LINQ and having some difficulty. Basically, I am trying to query a DataTable that holds navigation data for products (4 category levels of IDs & descriptions, e.g. Men's > Jackets > Summer > Pullover). The navigation category should appear sequentially and not have "repeats". What I mean by that is once a description occurs in the rows of data it can happen again, but once it changes to another description it cannot change back to that previous description. I have developed this SQL query in Access and it seems to do what I need it to do against my test data:

```
SELECT Count(Nav.Level1Text) AS CountOfLevel1Text, Nav.Level1ID, Nav.SO, Nav.DC, Nav.Language
FROM Nav
GROUP BY Nav.Level1ID, Nav.SO, Nav.DC, Nav.Language
HAVING Count(Nav.Level1Text) > 1;
```

Here is what I have gotten so far:

```
var query = from table in navTable.AsEnumerable()
            group table by new
                           {
                               Cat1Id = table["Cat1Id"],
                               Cat1Text = table["Cat1Desc"],
                               SalesOrg = table["SalesOrg"],
                               DistChan = table["DistChan"],
                               Language = table["Language"]
                            }
            into groupedTable
            where groupedTable.Key.Cat1Text.Count() > 1 //Count doesn't exist
            select new {Cat1Count = groupedTable.Key.Cat1Text.Count(), groupedTable.Key.Cat1Id, groupedTable.Key.SalesOrg,
            groupedTable.Key.DistChan, groupedTable.Key.Language};
```

It seems like I am pretty close, but I am having trouble with the "where" piece. I can't figure out how to get the count of Level1Text (there is no Cat1Text.Count method, but I left it in to demonstrate what I think it should do).

EDIT: So I realized I did not explain this very clearly, but the query detects when there is a Cat1Id assigned to 2 different Cat1Desc's. This is what I refer to as a "repeat". For example, if a Cat1Id of '1' with a Cat1Desc of 'Mens' occurs followed by a Cat1Id of '2' with a Cat1Desc of 'Womens', this query should let me know because the 'Count(Cat1Desc) > 1' with a different ID.

Comment: The hard part here is that a relational database table does not have a notion of sequence, let alone repetition. It knows about duplicates though. I think you want to detect duplicates for `Nav.Level1Text` within the five fields you group on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution and wanted to post so others could see:

```
var query = from table in navTable.AsEnumerable()
            group table by new
            {
                Cat1Id = table["Cat1Id"], SalesOrg = table["SalesOrg"],
                DistChan = table["DistChan"], Language = table["Language"]
            }
            into groupedTable
            where groupedTable.Select(x => x["Cat1Desc"]).Distinct().Count() > 1
            select new
            {
                Cat1Count = groupedTable.Select(x => x["Cat1Desc"]).Distinct().Count(),
                groupedTable.Key.Cat1Id, groupedTable.Key.SalesOrg,
                groupedTable.Key.DistChan, groupedTable.Key.Language
            };
```

It was important to remove 'Cat1Desc' from the group and then use the Distinct() in the 'where' and 'select'.

Comment: Note that you can use `let distinctCatDesc = groupedTable.Select(x => x["Cat1Desc"]).Distinct().Count()` right before the `where` and then use it in both the `where` and the `select` instead of re-calculating it.